# encode method python 3

Tags: python-3.x, encode

I'm converting an application from Ruby to Python, in Ruby, there is a force_encoding method used to encode the utf8 string. Now, in Python there is no exact match for force_encoding so, I'm using encode method instead but in since Python 3 method returns the bytes not string, but I need encoded string.

For ex:
   str1 = "abc"
   str2 = str1.encode("ascii") // returns the bytes

I need string instead bytes, can I used the decode method the same way like...

str1 = "abc"
   str2 = str1.encode("ascii").decode("ascii")

I'm confused the if the decode method converts the string again to the utf8 instead I need the ascii string.

And one more thing in Ruby there is method encoding to check the encoding type...

Ruby:
  str1 = "abc"
  print (str1.encoding)  // returns utf8

So, we can determine the string is utf8 encoded string is there anything similar to this in Python as well???

Answer (score 0):

> So, we can determine the string is utf8 encoded string is there anything similar to this in Python as well???

In Python 3 all strings are unicode encoded, so no need to check anything.

**UPD**: but if u are talking about bytes, I mean determine encoding of byte string, this can be accomplished something like this:

```
import chardet

the_encoding = chardet.detect(...)['encoding']
```